Difference between computed state and regular state?
I was told that I have been using too many states in my react project and that I should use computed state instead of using regular state but I am unable to understand what computed state really is, how to use it and when it is appropriate to use it and how it differs from regular state?
I have tried looking up resources on google but I still could not really grasp it. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

As a general life advice. If you don't understand what someone mean, ask them to clarify instead of turning to strangers on the internet. I could guess what he meant, but AFAIK computed state is not a broadly used term in react that means something specific.

Computed state is also called derived state: it's state that never needs to be changed independently from some other state. If a value is only changed as the result of some other state changing, it should be computed state instead of its own state.

Computed state refers to values that are derived from state or props. Computed state is reactive, exactly like normal state.
The advantage of a computed state is that you dont need to manually manage your derived state, react takes care of that for you.
I ripped this example from the react docs to show an example of it.
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('Taylor');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('Swift');
  // ✅ Good: calculated during rendering
  const fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  // ...
}


In the react documentation, they also have this list to decided if a value should be in a state or not. I find that usefull.
I think @Zxeenu's answer is correct. To elaborate when to use what you can use reacts documentation, they have this list.
Does it remain unchanged over time? If so, it isn’t state.
Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it isn’t state.
Can you compute it based on existing state or props in your component? If so,  it definitely isn’t state!
https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react#step-3-find-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state
